How to remove the wording "Total: " in apache superset "Pie Chart"?
I want to have only the big total number inside the Pie Chart, but without the word "Total: "
In the Pai chart settings I enabled "Show Total". But in the settings there is no value "Leave only the number". I assume that this can be done using the CSS code.

